# C# / UWP / MVVM - How to handle HttpClient exceptions when the server is unrechable

Tags: c#, exception, mvvm, uwp, httpclient

I am currently working on an UWP app, that will run on a Raspberry PI. Most of my application can be used without an internet connection, but parts of it rely on fetching data from a server ran locally.

**My issue is that whenever the server is offline, I can not handle the exceptions raised by the HttpClient.**

To avoid using async tasks in the constructor of the ViewModel, I've moved it to the OnLoaded method of the View.

These are the methods that I use:

**HomeAssistantView**

```cs
private async void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await ViewModel.LoadEntities();
}
```

**HomeAssistantViewModel**

```cs
public async Task LoadEntities()
{
    var entityList = await _homeAssistantService.LoadEntities();
    Switches = new ObservableCollection<HomeAssistantSwitchEntity>(entityList.OfType<HomeAssistantSwitchEntity>());
    Entities = new ObservableCollection<HomeAssistantEntity>(entityList.Where(entity =>!(entity is HomeAssistantSwitchEntity)));
}
```

**HomeAssistantService**

```cs
public async Task<List<HomeAssistantEntity>> LoadEntities()
{
    _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_homeAssistantURL);
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {_homeAssistantToken}");
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync("api/states");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return DeserializeConfigFile(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    return new List<HomeAssistantEntity>();
}
```

Even though I've added a try block, the application raises a `System.Exception`, with the message `"The server name or address could not be resolved"`. After disabling the generic `Exception` type in the settings, Visual Studio told me it was a type of `HttpRequestException` with the message `An error occurred while sending the request.`

In a different part of my application, where I use a weather API, I got away with using the `NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile()` to check whether there is an internet connection available prior to sending a request, but it's not a viable option here. Also, I've thought of sending a ping to the server prior to trying to fetch the data, but as far as I'm concerned, pinging is not available on the **Windows 10 IoT Core**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood, that, you don't want the exception to be thrown, is this correct?
If yes just replace

```
catch (HttpRequestException e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

with

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

this will catch all occuring exceptions

Comment: Initially I've set it to the generic Exception type, and that's when the "The server name or address could not be resolved" message was reported.

Comment: This is the answer, but you could explain it further. The reason the current catch is not working because it is throwing a System.AggregateException not a HttpRequestException, which is why it doesn't fall into the catch.

Comment: @RyanThomas thanks for the correction. I missed that in the answer.

Comment: I've set it to AggregateException, but it still raises a HttpRequestException.

Comment: You can imaging catch as a kind of guard. Only the defined type is catched by this guard. So I case you want to catch all possible Exceptions You either implement multiple catch-statements OR You can use the generic catch(Exception e) (all Exceptions are derived from Exception)

Comment: Oops. Turns out I've just set Visual Studio to break when a HttpRequestException occurs. Still, thank you very much for your help! :)